# How to check if a function is in progress in corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk

how do I check if a function is in progress? I want it to repeat itself if it isn't already in progress.

```
  local function move(event)
    ball.x = 100
     ball.y = 200
  transition.to(ball, {x=0, y=600, time = 5000})
  end


local function check(event)
  if( --THE OTHER FUNCTION IS IN PROGRESS)then
    --do something
  end
end


ball:addEventListener("touch", move)
```

Comment: Are Corona functions *ever* called at the same time? What you're asking for is essentially a mutex. Perhaps you mean the `transition` part, in which case it's an entirely different question - then you can simply set e.g. `transitionInProgress = true` and add `onComplete` to your `.to()` parameters that sets it to false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used corona, but this is a common javascript idiom and is typically the way you would do it there:

```
local currentlyMoving = false

local function move(event)
    ball.x = 100
    ball.y = 200
    currentlyMoving = true
    transition.to(
        ball, 
        { 
            x=0, 
            y=600, 
            time = 5000, 
            onComplete = function(obj) 
                currentlyMoving = false 
            end 
        })
end


local function check(event)
  if (not currentlyMoving) then
    --do something
  end
end


ball:addEventListener("touch", move)
```

You can find more details about the onComplete method [here](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/transition/to.html)

Comment: it works for when something is transitioning, but what about in general